# Incrementos numéricos

Tags: gramática

En inglés, a veces se dicen incrementos específicos como *hundreds*, *thousands*. ¿Se puede hacer lo mismo en español? ¿Es la siguiente oración correcta?

*Noté que las cifras de la población están en miles, pero las tasas están en 100.000 .*

---

In English we say *increments in hundreds* or *increments in thousands*. How does Spanish handle it? Is the above sentence correct?

Answer (score 3):

En cuanto a la primera pregunta, sí, se puede, se llaman "unidades" y se utilizan precisamente como el ejemplo que das: *decenas*, *cientos*, *miles*, *decenas de miles*, *cientos de miles*, *millones*, *decenas de millones*, etc.

Con lo anterior, la oración también está correcta y podrías escribir: *Noté que las cifras de la población están en miles pero las tasas están en cientos de miles*.

---

As for your first question, yes, you can, it's called "units" and they're used precisely like in your example: *tens*, *hundreds*, *thousands*, *tens of thousands*, *hundreds of thousands*, *millions*, *tens of millions*, etc.

With this, the sentence is correct.

Comment: No estoy verificando que es lo correcto, pero me suena mejor _decenas de millón_ que _decenas de millones_; igualmente _centenas de millón_, _miles de millón_ (o _millardos_), _decenas de miles de millón_, etc.

Comment: No lo había considerado de esa forma. ¿Qué explicaría que así fuese?

Comment: De la misma forma que decimos *una docena de huevos*, y no *una docena de huevo*, lo correcto es decir *una decena de millones*, como dice esta respuesta. *Decena de millón*, en singular, es la posición que ocupa en un número la séptima cifra empezando por el final.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con Gorpik, y es precisamente eso lo que inspiró mi explicación.

Comment: No encuentro en las páginas de RAE o Fundeu cual es la posición oficial, pero googleando tanto "decenas de millón" como "decenas de millones" observo lo siguiente:  En contextos matemáticos, para referirse a la posición de la octava cifra (de derecha a izquierda) se suele usar _“las decenas de millón”_ (en singular).  En otros contextos, cuando se suele hablar de cantidades que se escribirían con ocho cifras, se suele usar el plural: _“decenas de millones de personas o cosas”_.  Este uso me parece natural en mi idiolecto.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Pero el caso de la pregunta es el segundo que mencionas, no el primero. Por supuesto, en mi comentario he escrito *séptima cifra* por error, me refería a la octava, como bien dices.